# Could not find or load main class <classname>

Tags: java, gradle

I created one Spring boot gradle application. I have specified main class name in my build.gradle as

```
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
def appName = 'app'
buildDir = 'gradle-build'
mainClassName = 'package.Application'
dependencies{
   ----
}
configurations {
    compile.exclude group: 'ch.qos.logback'
}

jar {
    baseName = appName
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'app',
                'Implementation-Version': version,
                'Main-Class': mainClassName
    }
}

startScripts {
    applicationName = appName
}

distributions {
    main {
        baseName = appName
    }
}
```

when i run my main class from eclipse, it is running properly. But when I am executing the jar file that will be generated in gradle-build, it is throwing error "could not find or load main class ".

I am executing the command as

```
    java -jar app.jar
```

I tried with other commands as well

```
    java -cp -jar app.jar
    java -cp app.jar
```

In all the cases, I am getting same error.

And my manifest file is like this

```
 Manifest-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Title: app
Implementation-Version: 1.0.0
Main-Class: package.Application
```

Please help me solving this.

Comment: Have you tried to inform the whole path to the file? Example: `java -jar "C:/myworkspace/myproject/myjar.jar"`

Comment: yes. I did. No luck. I am using mac so I specified absolute path from "/users/till/jarfile"

Comment: do you have a a ``Main-Class`` entry in ``META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`` in the jar?

Comment: yes. There is entry.

Manifest-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Title: app
Implementation-Version: 1.0.0
Main-Class: package.Application

This is my Manifest file

Comment: When you use `java -cp` you inform your main class instead of the jar. `java -cp MyMainClass.class`

Comment: I have had this issue before and i got it fixed by updating all the libraries used to build my project. TL;DR i was using e.g. Hibernate Core 5.0.x to Maven build but had a Hibernate Core 4.0.x on the lib directory.

Comment: And does the class ``package.Application`` contain a valid ``main`` method?

Comment: @Julian: when i use java -cp package.Application.class . I got output as explanation about how to use java [options] etc.

Comment: @f1sh: yes, it does. I am able to run successfully from eclipse but not using jar.

Comment: ROFL. Check the libraries you're using and see if it's the same as stated on `pom.xml`

Comment: @Julian: I just checked now. There is no problem with libraries.

Comment: Well, i don't know then man. Sorry.

Comment: no problem. Thanks for the input @Julian

Comment: did you check that the jar-file contains the class? you can easly list all files with `jar -tf app.jar`

Comment: @Joshiste yes. It does contain the class.

Comment: How do you build the jar?

Comment: @Opal: using gradle (./gradlew clean build)

Answer (score 0):

i was having very similar problem.

Turns out the issue was that my Meta-INF, inside my jar file had some RSA, SF, AND dsa files.

change your jar declaration as follow

```
jar {
    baseName = appName
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'app',
                'Implementation-Version': version,
                'Main-Class': mainClassName
    }
    exclude ('META-INF/*.RSA', 'META-INF/*.SF','META-INF/*.DSA')
```

}